# Can you make it so that people can't break blocks unless they have placed them?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map where you can build houses and destroy **only blocks that the player has placed**. This is so he/she doesn't just go mining the scenery. 
Answering this will help me a lot.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is in Adventure mode. You could give them tools that can only break certain blocks and only give them those blocks.

So assume a player is only building a house out of construction materials like wood planks and stone bricks, give them a tool that can only break these types of blocks and natural blocks like grass, dirt, stone and wood will be unbreakable.

This would not stop them from going into a village and taking blocks from there, but if your goal is to build houses without breaking the scenery, this would work. You can always put other systems in place to protect villages specifically.